# Get the current bandwidth usage in cPanel?

Tags: php, api, cpanel, bandwidth

I have a regular cPanel account on my shared hosting, and I want to get the current bandwidth usage info using their API with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should ask your hosting providers or  you can check bandwidth usage from your cpanel under Logs >> bandwith.
Here you can check bandwidth by day or monthly.